blender4.22 python api normals_split_custom_set not working?
# This example assumes we have a mesh object selected

    import bpy
    
    import bmesh
    
    import numpy as np

# Get the active mesh

    me = bpy.context.object.data
    
    # Get a BMesh representation
    
    bm = bmesh.new() # create an empty BMesh
    
    bm.from_mesh(me) # fill it in from a Mesh
    
    vert_amnt = len(me.vertices)
    
    edge_amnt = len(me.edges)
    
    loop_amnt = len(me.loops)
    
    face_amnt = len(me.polygons)
    
    og_norms = np.zeros(loop_amnt*3, dtype=np.float32)
    
    me.loops.foreach_get('normal', og_norms)
    
    og_norms.shape = [loop_amnt, 3]
    
    #set all normals to 0
    
    for i in range(loop_amnt):
    
    og_norms[i] = [0,0,0]
    
    me.normals_split_custom_set(og_norms)
    
    #Finish up, write the bmesh back to the mesh
    
    bm.to_mesh(me)
    
    bm.free() 

In Blender 4.2, after using this script, the normals of the mesh did not change at all. Please help me!

Have you tried https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Mesh.html#bpy.types.Mesh.normals_split_custom_set ?
